# Car starts for 47 sec and then slowly stalls and dies every time

Tags: nissan, stall, vacuum-leak

I own a Nissan 300zx Z31 1985, a car which has been having the same recurring problem almost a dozen times now. I am usually able to fix this issue, however the fix is never successful permanently. This time I cannot fix the issue. The car runs and drives but will always die aprox. 47 seconds after starting it. It seems that once the fuel pump stops priming fuel to the engine and shuts off, the car stutters and dies very shortly after. Usually I disassemble the Mass Airflow sensor line from the air filter to the engine and make sure everything is tight and secure, and it often works for a few weeks before I have to do it again. I have tried to find vacuum leaks using Starter fluid however I have been quiet unsuccessful. I have swapped out the following in order to try and fix this problem:
- Mass Airflow Sensor
- Air filter
- Fuel filter
- Fuel Pump
- Spark Plugs
- Throttle position sensor
- All ignition/spark plug leads 
- Hose clamps
- Some older hoses (vacuum lines, fuel lines & coolant lines)

I'm unsure at the moment as to what I can do to fix my vehicle and I am very interested in finding a permanent solution to this problem. I cannot take this vehicle to a mechanic as I would have to navigate heavy traffic with a car that stalls every 47 seconds.

Any help and advice would be most greatly appreciated.

Thank you for reading!

Kind Regards,
Kail M.

Edit: ECU displaying error code 31 (Load Signal Circuit) and 23 (Throttle Valve switch). Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Take it to a mechanic on a trailer.

Comment: Managed to take it to the local mechanic, who could not pinpoint the problem. Their suggestion is to take it to the next town over to have an auto electrics expert to take a look. It's not worth the hassle of paying $200 to get it towed to the next town and then having no way to get back to it

Comment: check fuel line for blockages,

Comment: Have you read the codes? It does have an ECU, [here's a site](http://xenonzcar.com/z31/ECUcodes.html) that shows how to do it. Also, have you checked the fuel filter and your tank vent?

Comment: I don't know the answer but my gut feeling is the fuel pump relay.  If feels like the problem is that the fuel pump only runs when the priming circuit is live.  If it were mine, the first thing I'd try would be to hard-wire the fuel pump and see if it run for longer than 47 seconds in that configuration.

Comment: I replaced the fuel pump relay and tested a newer/functioning one, however I am still dealing with the same issue. As soon as I hear the relay flick off and the fuel pump shutdown, the car dies. I have just checked the ECU and am recieving an error code for 23 (throttle valve switch/idle switch circuit) & 31 (Load signal Circuit). Any ideas?

Comment: Check the exhaust system. I once worked on an older Nissan D21 truck with a throttle body that would lose power and die after several minutes. I came to discover the catalytic converter was blocked. The truck would run for a while and then die. The first fix treated the symptom and only changed the converter. The problem returned after several weeks. When the truck came back we came to understand one of the injectors was leaking and unburned fuel accumulated in the converter and burned it mostly closed. We changed the injectors and it fixed the issue for good.

Comment: Also, check the injectors and the injector ends. The injector ends are the connector ends that are part of the engine harness that attach to the injector. If you can mildly shake them and upset the idle, then you should replaced the ends. You buy them as a kit. You cut the old connector from the engine harness, and solder the new pig tail in its place with the new connector end. We used to replace them all the time when I worked at a Nissan dealership in the late 1990s. The VG-30 motors most frequently experienced the problem. I believe the older 300z's used that motor.